# Compilation error in assigning unsigned int to an enum of arrays within structure

Tags: c++, casting, enums

```
typedef struct {
uint64_t low;
uint64_t cache_size;
uint32_t range;
uint8_t cache;

/// Number of symbols in the tables
size_t count;

/// rc_encode()'s position in the tables
size_t pos;

/// Symbols to encode
enum {
    RC_BIT_0,
    RC_BIT_1,
    RC_DIRECT_0,
    RC_DIRECT_1,
    RC_FLUSH,
} symbols[RC_SYMBOLS_MAX];

/// Probabilities associated with RC_BIT_0 or RC_BIT_1
probability *probs[RC_SYMBOLS_MAX];

} lzma_range_encoder;
```

//Above is the structure.

//Below is the function

```
static inline void
rc_bit(lzma_range_encoder *rc, probability *prob, uint32_t bit)
{
rc->symbols[rc->count] = bit;      // problem code line 69
rc->probs[rc->count] = prob;
++rc->count;
}
```

//Error:
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'uint32_t' to 'lzma_range_encoder::'
        Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)

'bit' is uint32_t which needs to be stored(type-casted) in lzma_range_encoder->symbols, but I am not able to do it somehow.
tried every p&c. Also, searched earlier questions regarding this(static_cast and all but no luck)

It is a simple problem I guess. But I am stuck since 2 days. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Why you want cast, instead of use enum here? Your enum is unnamed, so you cannot cast to this type (only by usage decltype in C++11 i think).

Comment: So what is symbols[RC_SYMBOLS_MAX]; here.

Comment: It's not name. It's array of this unnamed enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a *name* to the enumeration:

```
enum symbol_enum
{
    // ...
} symbols[RC_SYMBOLS_MAX];
```

Then you can cast to it:

```
rc->symbols[rc->count] = static_cast<lzma_range_encoder::symbol_enum>(bit);
```

PS. In C++ you don't need to use `typedef` for structures or classes. The normal structure name can be used as-is.

Comment: That compiled fine. Thanks Joachim.

Comment: ForEveR: got your point. Silly mistake. Actually this code base is not mine. I am directly compiling this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following thing with unnamed enum with C++11.

```
enum {
    RC_BIT_0,
    RC_BIT_1,
    RC_DIRECT_0,
    RC_DIRECT_1,
    RC_FLUSH,
} symbols[RC_SYMBOLS_MAX];

rc->symbols[rc->count] = 
static_cast<std::decay<std::decltype(*symbols)>::type>(bit);
```

Comment: @user1881950 include type_traits header.

Comment: Both answers worked great. But can only accept 1 one them currently. Thanks ForEveR and Joachim